# Unable to connect to MySQL after deploying my application

Tags: java, mysql

I have installed MySQL to my local computer. I can access MySQL from my Java Application which is running on my computer.

My connection string is `private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase"` which allows me to connect successfully. But when I deploy my application to other computers on my LAN and try to connect to my MySQL databases from the other computers I can't access my database.

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: What *exact* error do you get? And is MySQL running on the same port on that machine?

Comment: You don't use this exact same URL to connect to your machine from other machines, do you?

Comment: I haven't got an error. The java application is running succesfull on my computer. On my computer I have a MySql server. I will connect that server from other LAN computers with using my java application. when I running my java procet on other computer and trying connection to my databese nothing happens , I'm seeing only my application window :-) what can I do to connecting from lan computers to my mysql database

Comment: No I'm using this url (private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase") to connect my machine from other machines.Is it wrong what should I do

Comment: Do you know what "[localhost](http://superuser.com/questions/196893/difference-between-localhost-and-the-ip-address)" means?  It's a "special address"; it means *this computer, and this computer only*! :)

Comment: `localhost` is the computer running the application. If the mysql server is on another machine, change `localhost` to the name of the other machine.

Comment: My computer name is MYCOMP and I changed the url so : (private String url = "jdbc:mysql://MYCOMP:3306/mydatabase") but nothing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned in the comments, you issue is your connection string: `private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase"`

In order for you to be able to connect to your database from other machines on your LAN you will need to change `localhost` to your IP address. For example:

`private String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.10:3306/mydatabase"`

Providing that the other machines can see 192.168.0.10 they will be able to connect (with the right credentials of course!)

Comment: On cmd I'm writing ipconfig to cmd on my computer. And I have an ip4 adress 192.168.x.x and I change my url so (private String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.x.x:3306/mydatabase") but nothing... Must I open 3306 port? if so where can I open it to LAN access

Comment: Port 3306 would need to be allowed via your firewall, without knowing your network setup, I would hazard a guess that you'll be using windows firewall. Check this link for a how to: http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/open-a-port-in-windows-7s-firewall/

Comment: I'm changed my url `private String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.x.x:3306/mydatabase"` 192.168.x.x is my computer's ip adress. After that I opened 3306 port . Than I added a new user from localhost/phpmyadmin which have ALL PRIVILAGES and host is '%'. Than I run my application on other computer and is sucessfull run. :-)

Comment: Glad to hear it, and welcome to stack overflow! Don't forget to mark your answers as accepted to help others find the answers to your questions.